# PHP Warning [function.include]: failed to open stream

Tags: php, include

http://smiths-heimann.az/index.php?feat=1 please check out this page.  My php code looks like that.

```
<?php 
/*at the top of the page*/
if (!isset($feat)){
if (isset($_GET['page'])) 
{
    $page=$_GET['page'];
    }   
if (!isset($_GET['page']) && !isset($_GET['feat'])) 
{
    $page=1;
    }       
${'page'.$page}='class="current"';
}
    if (isset($_GET['feat']) && !isset($_GET['page']))
    {
    $feat=$_GET['feat'];
    }
....
/*content*/

        if(isset($page) && isset($_GET['id']) && !isset($_GET['subid']))
        include "core/content/pages/".$page.$_GET['id'].".php";
        if(isset($page) && isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['subid']))
        include "core/content/pages/".$page.$_GET['id'].$_GET['subid'].".php";
        if(isset($page) && !isset($_GET['id']) && !isset($_GET['subid'])) 
        include "core/content/pages/".$page.".php";  /*line 136*/
        if (isset($feat) && !isset($_GET['page']))
    {
    $feat=$_GET['feat'];
    include "core/content/pages/featured.php";
        } 
        ?>
```

What's the problem? Please help

Comment: is it your filename ? nclude(core/content/pages/class="current".php)

Comment: `core/content/pages/class="current".php` seems to be invalid file name. are u sure it is on the filesystem?

Comment: and it's sooooo unsecure to include a page which name is sent by `$_GET`

Comment: it's not a big project but simple website. i don't care if it's sercure/unsecure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the rest of the error on your website:

```
No such file or directory
```

The path or the filename is incorrect.  It looks like the problem is with this line:

```
${'page'.$page}='class="current"';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have looked in your warning, then it says that unable to find

```
Warning: include(core/content/pages/class="current".php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/heimann/public_html/index.php on line 136
```

page..

I am sure there is no such page like class="current".php ....

little bug .. I am sure you can eliminate it easily

error lies on

```
${'page'.$page}='class="current"';
```

line

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE

```
        if(isset($page) && isset($_GET['id']) && !isset($_GET['subid']))
        include "core/content/pages/".$page.$_GET['id'].".php";
        if(isset($page) && isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['subid']))
        include "core/content/pages/".$page.$_GET['id'].$_GET['subid'].".php";
        if(isset($page) && !isset($_GET['id']) && !isset($_GET['subid'])) 
        include "core/content/pages/".$page.".php";  /*line 136*/
```

WITH

```
        if(isset($page) && isset($_GET['id']) && !isset($_GET['subid']))
        @include "core/content/pages/".$page.$_GET['id'].".php";
        if(isset($page) && isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['subid']))
        @include "core/content/pages/".$page.$_GET['id'].$_GET['subid'].".php";
        if(isset($page) && !isset($_GET['id']) && !isset($_GET['subid'])) 
        @include "core/content/pages/".$page.".php";  /*line 136*/
```

**NOTE**

When 'isset($_GET['id'])' is true... You should make sure that $page is set properly

Comment: ok, so he won't see warning, but it won't solve the problem either

Comment: I only suppressed the warnings.. I hope $page is set well when isset($_GET['id'])==true!

Comment: @Luchian Grigore prevents function from raising error or warning

Comment: sorry, but... how something that doesn't even try to be a solution can be accepted answer?!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

Replaced

```
/*at the top of the page*/
if (!isset($feat)){
if (isset($_GET['page'])) 
{
    $page=$_GET['page'];
    }   
if (!isset($_GET['page']) && !isset($_GET['feat'])) 
{
    $page=1;
    }       
${'page'.$page}='class="current"';
}
    if (isset($_GET['feat']) && !isset($_GET['page']))
    {
    $feat=$_GET['feat'];
    }
```

with

```
if (!isset($feat)){
if (isset($_GET['page'])) 
{
    $page=$_GET['page'];
    ${'page'.$page}='class="current"';
    }   
if (!isset($_GET['page']) && !isset($_GET['feat'])) 
{
    $page=1;
    ${'page'.$page}='class="current"';
    }       

}
    if (isset($_GET['feat']) && !isset($_GET['page']))
    {
    $feat=$_GET['feat'];
    }
```